# OS Walk Improper File

Tags: python, glob

This code worked perfectly fine on my mac but when I tried it on windows it's giving me a improper filename which is messing up the entire code.

```
exclude = set(['Images', 'Notes','Programs'])
for root,dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\***\OneDrive\Desktop\Program',topdown=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
    #Loop through all the files in the current directory
    print(f"Processing: {root[80:]}")
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg') or file.endswith('.jpeg') or file.endswith('.png'):
            img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, file))
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

```
C:\Users\***\OneDrive\Desktop\Program\._Images30.png
```

This is the path I am getting when I am looking for `C:\Users\***\OneDrive\Desktop\Program\.Images30.png` without the underscore.

Comment: I don't see how that code could work on macOS given that the glob is obviously only valid on Windows. It would only work on macOS because the `os.walk()` returns nothing on macOS and thus doesn't execute the body of that loop. Also, what do you mean by "improper filename"? Your question is incoherent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are facing of filenames starting with "._" may be caused while copying files from mac to windows (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/851373/hide-macs-dot-underscore-files-on-a-windows-share-in-a-mixed-user-environm)). Macs use these files to store metadata about the original file. You can make the following change in your code to ignore files that start with `._`:

```
for file in files:
    if file.startswith('._'):
        # Skip over filenames that start with an underscore character
        continue
    if file.endswith('.jpg') or file.endswith('.jpeg') or file.endswith('.png'):
        img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, file))
        print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: `On Windows, filenames with spaces are not allowed, so they are converted to underscores.` - this is wrong, where did you get this from?

Comment: The only characters not allowed in windows file names are 
    < (less than)
    > (greater than)
    : (colon)
    " (double quote)
    / (forward slash)
    \ (backslash)
    | (vertical bar or pipe)
    ? (question mark)
    * (asterisk)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: @FlyingTeller when you run a code in command prompt you are not allowed to type file names with spaces it shows error. As of my knowledge you can save them with spaces but you can't call them when the names are saved with spaces however you can call them by replacing the spaces with underscores.

Comment: @FlyingTeller sorry for the wrong reply. i thought it was not allowed. Because, once i am never able to call the file names with spaces in command prompt

Comment: This is not that they are not allowed, but the command prompt cannot distinguish if a space seperates the path/name of a program or if it seperates arguments. Simple solution is to wrap filenames/paths with spaces with quotes

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes, i just read about the quoting the file names. thanks for the correction

Comment: Please correct/delete your answer accordingly

Comment: @FlyingTeller i have made some changes is it right now??

Comment: No, it's still not right.  Spaces are PERFECTLY FINE in file names (as witness by the directory "Program Files").  If you are using them in a command line, then you have to use spaces to help the command line parser, but you do not use quotes when you're opening the file, because quote marks are ALSO fine in a file name.  Your answer is just on the wrong track.

Comment: @TimRoberts you need not save it with quote marks. but when you are running it . you need to put it in the quote marks. that is what i am saying. which quite obvious

Comment: To clarify. When you are referring to a path that has spaces in a terminal, you will always need to do something special like wrapping it in quotes or escaping the spaces, this is nothing windows specific, but comes from the fact that terminals use spaces to seperate individual arguments. All this is irrelevant when you are interacting with paths from python. You can have as many spaces as you like, no problem. Additionally, there is no mechanism that would magically create underscores in paths that don't have them.

Comment: This would be highly problematic behaviour since `some filename.jpg` and `some_filename.jpg` could both exist in the same folder

Comment: Your answer goes in the wrong direction from the start since the whole space issue does not come up within python, unless you are trying to interact with a terminal through `subprocess`

Comment: You claim it's obvious but it is entirely wrong.  If you have a file called `A B C.txt`, you open it in Python with `open('A B C.txt','r')`.  You do NOT use quotes.  You need to use quotes if you are in a command shell, because the shell can't tell whether that's one name or three parameters.

Comment: I suggest you make some experiments yourself in python. Create a file "some filename.txt" and then try to do `open("some filename.txt")` or `"open(some_filename.txt)"`

Comment: @FlyingTeller i agree with you.. i realized that i was wrong and the problem occurs while copying the files from mac to windows https://superuser.com/q/851373

Comment: @TimRoberts i have edited my answer now , if it is good then can you upvote it now?

Comment: I think it would be better to ignore (i.e do `continue`) when your loop over `os.walk` has a file like that. You will come across the actual image eventually (if it is present), but with your approach you would either process the same image twice (if the actual image is present), or would cause an unexpected error (in case the metadata is still present, but you have deleted the actual image). So `if file.startswith("._"): continue`

Comment: Here's a valid filename for you: **ABC._BAR** Now consider what your code would do if it came across such a filename

Comment: @DarkKnight agreed. i have edited the answer . thanks for the remark

Comment: The first sentence in your answer needs to be modified. Instead of "is caused" it should read "may be caused". Filenames beginning with '._' are valid (albeit not recommended) and could have been created by any application

Comment: @DarkKnight i used to write "may be " but eveytime i did that many people devoted my answers and i was flooded with comments saying that you are uncertain of your answer we talk about facts here and not assumptions.

Comment: @nischalsharma In this case, your original wording is wrong and the use of "may be" is entirely correct

Comment: @DarkKnight its done now.... can you upvote it?